# Rinkeby faucet not working with Metamask?

Tags: ethereum, metamask

It says the account has successfully been funded, but ETH does not show up in my wallet under the Rinkeby test network.  This has happened several times over the past few days, i've tried different metamask wallets in both chrome and firefox.

Comment: Can you use a different test network? Maybe a good option.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't about programming.

Comment: For non-programming questions about Ethereum, try [ethereum.se].

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be having issues. For a small amount of ETH, I suggest you to try: http://rinkeby-faucet.com/
This will give you .001 Rinkeby Testnet ETH.

Answer (score -1):

is it possible that your import the accounts from ganache. And are trying to send test ETH from faucets t that account. Those accounts don't exist on rinkeby only on your private network. Try creating a new account in metamask and send some ETH there.